# Set tooltip on custom leafletjs control

Tags: javascript, tooltip, leaflet

I have made several custom buttons in Leafletjs - now I would like to add a hover-over tooltip to explain what the button does. I've tried putting a "title:" and "tooltip:" in the options but still do not see the text when I hover over the control.

```
var load = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'topright'

    },

    onAdd: function(map) {
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control leaflet-control-load-points');

        //container.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        container.style.width = '25px';
        container.style.height = '25px';

        container.onclick = function() {
            clear_markers(markers);
            load_markers(markers);
        }
        return container;
    },
});
```

Comment: You could try [hint.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/)

Comment: The URL seems to be broken, a mere six years later. Whart on earth are the inter-tubes coming to??!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question I was using the wrong approach to add the title option. By creating the container first and then setting the title after I was able to populate the title field and have a tooltip work on hover over.

```
var load = L.Control.extend({
    options: {position: 'topright'},
    onAdd: function(map) {
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control leaflet-control-load');
        container.title = "Enter Tooltip Here"
    }
});
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work with HTML in the title :-(